# Prove that $\varphi\left(T\right)=T^{-1}$ are continuous where $T$ operator defined

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

---

*Problem :*

Let $\varphi$ application such that :

$$\varphi~~~~:~\mathcal{L}_{r}\left(E\right)\to~~~~\mathcal{L}_{r}\left(E\right)$$
$$\varphi\left(T\right)=T^{-1}$$
• prove that $\varphi$ are continuous

---

$\color{red}{note}~"\color{pink}{operator~~regular}":~$

$(E,\|.\|)$ banach space & $~~T\in \mathcal{L}\left(E\right)$

$$T\in\mathcal{L}_{r}\left(E\right)\iff~T\left(E\right)=E~\wedge~T^{-1}~\text{existe}~\wedge~T^{-1}\in \mathcal{L}\left(E\right)$$

---

**My attempts :**

We have :

$~T^{-1}\in \mathcal{L}\left(E\right)\implies \exists~C>0~:~\|T^{-1}x\|_{E}\leq~C\|x\|_{E}$

And also

$\implies~\exists~k>0~~:~~\|Tx\|\geq~k\|x\|$

So ,

$\|\varphi\|_{\mathcal{L}_{r}\left(E\right)}=\|T^{-1}\|_{\mathcal{L}_{r}\left(E\right)}$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\leq~C\|x\|\leq_{k=C}$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\leq\|Tx\|\leq\|T\|\|x\|$

Is my attempt mathematically correct?

Is there any other way I would to see ?

---

**Thanks!**

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2535552/27978

Comment: The goal is to show that the operator $T \mapsto T^{-1}$ is continuous, the answer does not depend on a specific $T$.